# C++ assignment operator in while

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, pointers, assignment-operator

Can somebody explain how this piece of code works? The assignment operator in while is not a mistake, I did it on purpose. If I put N values in str1, the output is N*2-1 stars. In this case, the output is 0 stars.

The code in main is:

```
char str1[] = "";
char str2[10];

char *p1 = str1;
char *p2 = str2;

while(*p2++ = *p1++)
    cout << "* ";

return 0;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want us to explain to you the code you wrote yourself?

Comment: "If I put N values in str1, the output is N*2-1 stars." For me it's exactly N stars. Also, the warning might explain whats happening: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/699469325df59943

Comment: @NathanOliver: Why are you being snide towards a new user? And - how does your comment help him improve the question (or otherwise)?

Comment: @einpoklum This guy clearly is letting us do his homework. Stackoverflow wasn't built for that.

Comment: @einpoklum Thank you! My friend had this question at a test and I couldn't understand why the answer is 0 at first, then I didn't know why the stars are N*2-1 so that's why I asked for help.

Comment: @OpenGLManiac: 1. OP may very well not interpret NathanOliver's comment as what you've written; hell, I wasn't clear that that's what he meant. OP could very well think "What? No, I'm not." 2. Much better to just say that explicitly at the cost of sounding less witty.

Comment: Don't worry, you're not doing my homework and I don't understand what kind of homework it could be. If you can't help you can just skip this question, have a nice week. :)

Comment: @user3136734: Welcome to StackOverflow. Note that since there's a very high volume of questions posted to the site, people have become somewhat jaded and sometimes are not very courteous when it appears a question is inappropriate (e.g. having us solve your homework for you). Don't be disheartened by the attitude - you got a valid answer by RSahu.

Comment: @einpoklum thank you! I know that but I don't even see how can this be seen as solving a homework. It's just a code I can't understand and ask if someone can explain it to me, it was not me who wrote it (obviously, if I have no idea how it works). However, it's fine because I don't like doing other people's homework as well so I understand their reaction if they thought so! Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 4):

The conditional of the `while` statement can be thought of as:

```
(*p2++ = *p1++) != 0
```

which can be thought of as,

```
(*p2++ = *p1++), *(p2-1) != 0
```

since `p2` is post-incremented in the line.

The loop will continue until the null character from the string that `p1` points to is copied to the string that `p2` points to.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Turned out the output is not N*2-1 stars but N from the beginning, my friend just mistook the values of the first array. It all makes sense now, thanks and have a nice weekend. :)